# How does sklean LinearSVC classify the test cases which are on the boundary?

Tags: scikit-learn

I just did an experiment. I provided only two training cases [0, 1] and [1, 0]. They belong to two different categories. The test cases is [0, 0], which is on the decision boundary. The classifier assigns it to class 0. Is it because class 0 is the first class? Does it really make sense?

```
>>> X=numpy.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
>>> y=numpy.array([0,1])
>>> clf.fit_transform(X,y)
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0]])

>>> clf.predict(numpy.array([[0,0]]))
array([0])
>>> clf.decision_function(numpy.array([[0,0]]))
array([ 0.])
>>> clf.coef_
array([[ 0.66666667, -0.66666667]])
>>> clf.predict(numpy.array([[0,1]]))
array([0])
>>> clf.decision_function(numpy.array([[0,1]]))
array([-0.66666667])
>>> clf.intercept_
array([ 0.])
>>> clf.intercept_ > 0
array([False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would take your experiment as the answer to the question.

Points sitting on the decision boundary are ambiguous. What should the behavior be? Should it predict one of the two classes? Error out? Predict NaN?

By your experiment, scikit-learn predicts `0`. I would take that to mean that in the general case, it chooses the first (in lexicographical order) for the boundary cases.

If the boundary case matters for your application, you will have to write special code that checks the decision function for exact 0, and does something different. Like this:

```
scores = clf.decision_function( X )
predictions = scores > 0
preidctions[ scores==0 ] = np.nan
```